# TypeORM - orderBy with value

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

I have a problem with ordering records by value from my `SomeEnum`, here is my code

```
export enum SomeEnum{
    IMPORTANT = 'Important',
    NICE_TO_READ = 'Nice to read',
    OPINION = 'Opinion'
}

@Entity()
export class SomeEntity extends GenericEntity {

    //some columns 

    @Column({
        nullable: true
    })
    label: SomeEnum;
}
```

```
const wiki = await this.conn.getRepository(SomeEntity).createQueryBuilder('some')
            .where('some.id = :id', { id: someId})
            .orderBy() //HERE
```

I want to sort my data, so that all records containing the value `Important` from `SomeEnum` are at the top ot my response, how to do this?

thanks for any help!

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

You can use *case* in orderby, something like :

```
const wiki = await this.conn.getRepository(SomeEntity).createQueryBuilder('some')
            .where('some.id = :id', { id: someId})
            .orderBy(`(CASE WHEN some.label  IS ${SomeEnum.IMPORTANT} THEN 1 ELSE some.label END)`)
```

Comment: it return me `Error: "CASE WHEN some" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?`

Answer (score 0):

```
const wiki = await this.conn.getRepository(SomeEntity).createQueryBuilder('some')
            .where('some.id = :id', { id: someId})
            .orderBy(`(CASE WHEN some.label  IS ${SomeEnum.IMPORTANT} THEN 1 ELSE some.label END)`)
            .getRawMany();
```

use it with getRawMany() or getRawAndEntities();

sometimes you need to select some specific data,This data is not an entity, it's called raw data. To get raw data, you use getRawOne and getRawMany

See the [documentation on QueryBuilder](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-values-using-querybuilder) here for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this to avoid the error of `alias was not found. Maybe you forget to join.`

```
const wiki = await this.conn.getRepository(SomeEntity).createQueryBuilder('some')
            .where('some.id = :id', { id: someId})
            .orderBy(`(CASE WHEN some_label  IS ${SomeEnum.IMPORTANT} THEN 1 ELSE some_label END)`)
            .getRawMany();
```